# Trouble accessing ModelState Errors in view

Tags: c#, .net, html, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

So I am having some trouble accessing my model errors within my Razor view.

In my controller, when either the `ModelState` is not valid or some other custom validation does not pass, I add model errors like this: `ModelState.AddModelError("ModelState", "Please fill out all required fields.");`

Then I return a redirect like so:

```
return RedirectToAction("Register", "Account");
```

Seems fairly simple, however, when I try and access the model state errors, loop through them, and add them each as a separate `span` to my view, I get nothing at all displayed. Here's the code in the view:

```
@foreach (var error in ViewData.ModelState.Values.SelectMany(modelState => modelState.Errors))
{
    <span>@error.ErrorMessage</span>
    <br />
}
```

Am I doing something wrong here, or not doing something I should be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not redirect to action, just return same view:

```
///
/// Displays form to edit model
///
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
    MyModelClass m = new MyModelClass();
    return View(m);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(MyModelClass m)
{

    if( !ModelState.IsValid )
    {
        // Got error, return view
        return View(m);
    }
    return RedirectToAction("/mymodel/success");
}
```

**Updated**: ModelState.IsValid - mistyped :)

Comment: Ah, thank you! I guess when it was redirecting, all of the `ModelState` collections were cleared so it could prepare for another route. Didn't even think of that but it makes sense and now it works. Thank you!

Comment: Yes, this is main difference between redirect and forward